# Firefox not sending POST data to server

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, post, send

I can't seem to send ANY data to the server. Even tough I can in some of the other pages that I have. The only difference is that I am using a file upload in this perticular form. All works well in chrome.

Where is the error?

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#addnewadform").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    cache:false,
                    url: "/call/insert-standart-add.call.php", //URL IS CORRECT
                    type: "post",             // this is OK too
                    data: {submitStandartPost:'im sending the submit button value'}, //this is a super-simplified version of what i want the server to recieve
                    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',//i have tried a ton of different values for this
                    processData: false, //think this should be false for file uploads
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data!==''){
                            console.log(data);
                        }else{
                            console.log("nothing was sent");
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

The server does not recieve anything, but the script itself is being called.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitStandartPost'])){

}else{
 echo 'no input';
}
```

maybe the error has nothing to do with file upload. I have tried to remove the file upload and enctype='multipar/bal bla bal'. just does not work. No errors being logged

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Add an `error` method to your jQuery ajax call. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Use FormData

var data = new FormData();

Comment: Maybe sounds funny but try to add 2 dots before url (../call/insert-standart-add.call.php), hope it helps.

Comment: can you look at the site with your own eyes?
Open this http://borissprojects.com/standart-ad in chrome and firefox

Comment: I FIGURED OUT!! firefox does not send submit input value! interesting why tough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate HTML at times...

Anyway. The best way of avoiding this issue is in a clear cross-browser way is not to use $_POST['submit'] button because it's just not reliable.

so, for example, **don't** do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//do my form logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that FireFox does not send the submit input's value. In PHP's $_POST it simply does not exist.

As for fixing that, I don't have any idea.